# Should the s in spirit of Christmas be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, christmas

Should the s in spirit of Christmas be capitalized when in a sentence?

Comment: Only if you mean the *embodiment* of Christmas, or a specific, individual, spirit, such as the last who visited Scrooge.  If you mean the atmosphere of merriment, happiness, generosity, good will to men, then no.

Comment: What if you mean booze?

Comment: Observance of my religion/belief-system puts a very strong barrier/pressure towards me from capitalizing the "s" in "spirit" of Christmas.

Answer (score 2):

'spirit' is not a proper noun, so it wouldn't be capitalized.  If it was the title of a story, book, etc., then it would be capitalized

Comment: Well said! I agree with that.

Comment: I also agree. Spirit here does not refer to any deity. :)